Does death entering into the world through the original sin mean animals were also created eternal?
Romans 5:12

sin came into the world through one man, and his sin brought death with it

Death above can also mean the death of animals. It could mean that animals were going to die as a result of the original sin, does this imply animals were also created eternal originally?

The answer is "very probably" yes but we are not told specifically.

@Dottard, that is why I wonder what the original plan of God was because animals were eternal as Adam and Eve, sin disrupted this plan and brought about the plan for salvation to save us from death

Again, we are not told the details so we cannot know.

We may infer certain things from scripture which scripture does not openly state. I suggest this is such a case. This particular matter is not so stated because scripture is delivered for a very specific purpose and all of its contents are deliberately consistent to that Divine Purpose. In that we see longevity being remarkably shortened after the Flood, so we might suggest that animal life was similarly affected before the Flood.

Let's simply look at what the Bible does not say:

It does not state that plant or animal death was introduced the
moment Adam sinned (Romans 5:12, 1 Corinthians 15:21).

If animals were killed, Genesis 3:21 does not say that the creatures killed to make Adam and Eve’s clothing were the first animals to die. (Some theologians say this)
It's an assumption that there was no death of any kind before Adam sinned. This is not stated in the Bible.
Genesis 2:9 says that: The tree of life was in the midst of the garden. Was this not the means by which Adam and Eve were to live forever?

Genesis 3:22 ESV - Then the Lord God said, “Behold, the man has
become like one of us in knowing good and evil. Now, lest he reach out his hand and take also of the tree of life and eat, and live forever—”

If the tree of life was the means Adam and Eve were to live forever, two possible arguments arise. The first argument might look something like this:

Premise 1: The tree of life was necessary for Adam and Eve to live
forever.
Premise 2: If the tree of life was necessary for Adam and Eve to live
forever, then any being that did not have access to the tree of life
could not live forever.
Premise 3: If animals did not have access to the tree of life they cannot live forever.
Conclusion: Therefore, animals without access could not live forever.

We might write a second argument for the death of plants:

Premise 1: God gave permission to eat fruit.
Premise 2: Eating fruit results in the death of the fruit’s flesh and
its seeds (if they get chewed up).
Premise 3: The fruit’s flesh and its seeds are alive and made of
living cells.
Conclusion: Therefore, God’s permission to eat fruit implies the
death of the fruit’s flesh and its seeds.

According to Matt Fradd, a Byzantine Catholic and apologist:

If the tree of life was unique, it might have been enough for Adam and
Eve to eat from, but it would never have been enough for all of the
animals of the world to eat from. This may be another sign that the
animals were not understood to have the tree of life for their food.
If so, then the text of Genesis itself would suggest that, while man
was meant to be immortal, animals were not. That would support the
idea, based on St. Paul’s statement, that it was human death that
entered the world through the Fall, not animal death.

Thomas Aquinas also wrote in his Summa Theologica:

In the opinion of some, those animals which now are fierce and kill
others, would, in that state, have been tame, not only in regard to
man, but also in regard to other animals. But this is quite
unreasonable. For the nature of animals was not changed by man’s sin,
as if those whose nature now it is to devour the flesh of others,
would then have lived on herbs, as the lion and falcon. [1]

To conclude: I do not think that scripture allows us to assume that there was no death of any kind before Adam sinned.

death entered into the world through sin, it does not say our death is any different from the death of animals, it says generally death entered into the world

I do not promote this as "right," just "an" answer. We can see that Paul’s focus here is on death spreading to men. At the very least he’s not literally talking about the death of animals or plants. Note: Therefore, just as sin came into the world through one man, and death through sin, and so death spread to all men because all sinned— for sin indeed was in the world before the law was given, but sin is not counted where there is no law. Yet death reigned from Adam to Moses, even over those whose sinning was not like the transgression of Adam, who was a type of the one who was to come.

Your first argument is brilliant, Jason. A +1 for you and OP.

+1 for tackling the question whether the answer is right or not! I tend to agree, since I can't believe that God would create mosquitos to live forever. BTW, think the question as been asked previously.
